# PHP fopen succeeding for one script but not another

Tags: php, permissions, fopen

My following method uses an array of data `$FDFData` to create an FDF file:

```
    public function writeFDFFile($FDFData) {
        $fdf_file = time().'.fdf';
        $fdf = $this->createFDF(PDF_FORM, $FDFData);

        // write the file out
        if($fp=fopen($fdf_file,'w')) {
            fwrite($fp,$fdf,strlen($fdf));
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Unable to create file: '.$fdf_file);
        }

        fclose($fp);
        return $fdf_file;
    }
```

One of my scripts runs absolutely fine:

```
require_once('PDFPrinter.php');
try {
    $printer = new PDFPrinter();
    $FDFData = $printer->assembleFDFData(9);
    $fdf_file = $printer->writeFDFFile($FDFData);
    $printer->downloadFile($fdf_file);
}catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

but I can't get my test code to run because I get a:

```
Unexpected PHP error [fopen(1315558352.fdf) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: Permission denied]
```

error thrown:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/simpletest/autorun.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../PDFPrinter.php');
class PDFPrinterTest extends UnitTestCase {

    private $printer;
    private $FDFData;

    function setUp() {
        $this->printer = new PDFPrinter();
        $this->FDFData = $this->printer->assembleFDFData(5);
    }

    function testException() {
        try {
            $this->printer->writeFDFFile($this->FDFData);
            $this-assertTrue(true);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            $this->assertTrue(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Both scripts are run in directories with the correct permissions. I am running my test scripts through the browser as well, so it's not that I have a different environment.

I'm stuck as to how to proceed to find the issue really.

My directory structure:

```
HOME - PDFPrinter.php
  |
  -----tests - PDFPrinterTest.php
         |
         ------simpletest - autorun.php
```

Any suggestions as to how I could find the issue?

Many thanks

**Update**

I have tried changing my test class so that the only test function in there is:

```
function testWrite() {
    try {
        $name = "testing.txt";
        if($fp=fopen($name, 'w')) {
            fwrite($fp, "Blah");
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Nope.");
        }
    $this->pass("All good");
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $this->fail("Not good");
    }

}
```

but the exception is still thrown with the warning.

Yet a very simple script run from the same directory works fine:

```
$name = "Test.txt";
if($fp=fopen($name, 'w')) {
    fwrite($fp, "Working");
} else {
    throw new Exception("Nope.");
}
fclose($fp);
```

that will actually create and write to the file.

Comment: How is SAFE_MODE set? It normally gives errors because it can only upload to folders it created itself for safety reasons.

Comment: Hi SAFE_MODE is `off` for the local value and 'on' for the master value. When you say "it can only upload to folders it created itself", what is it 'it' you are refering to? Also, I have tried to move my test code to the same folder as the working code and I still get the same error.

Comment: Hi ! Appart for a directory permission, I do not see reason for the tests failure. what OS are you running your scripts on ? Have you tried to run your working from the tests directory ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Yes I have tried to run the working script from the tests directory and it works fine. I'm not sure of the OS. Rather annoyingly I have only been given ftp access to the server so I can't use command line to explore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution which was that the file name needed to be the full absolute address in order for it to work in both scripts for some reason. This was suggested [in one of the answers for this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882244/php-fopen-permission-denied) which I quote below:

> Use fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'test.txt','a+');

so for my code, I have used:

```
if($fp=fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$name, 'w')) {
    fwrite($fp, "Working");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your test

```
fwrite("Blah");
```

should be

```
fwrite($fp, "Blah");
```

I'm not sure what the problem in the original code is though.

Comment: That's true thanks, but it's failing on the line before that and the original code is correct. I'll update the post.

Answer (score 0):

> failed to open stream: Permission denied

There is one important programmer's skill every developer ought to master.
Here it is:

## To trust your eyes

If your PHP telling you that permission is denied - so it is. Just doble-check it.  It is not a big deal yet noone can do it for you.

Comment: I don't doubt it. But I can't find the reason for it.