# PHP can't write outside of the document root no matter what

Tags: php, apache, centos, chmod, chown

Running a VM with CentOS 5.7 with typical httpd install.

I'm trying to write a file to a folder outside of `/var/www/html`, lets say in `/var/somedir`

- I've chmoded somedir with 777
- I chowned it to apache:apache (root:apache didn't work either)
- PHP's safe_mode is off
- PHP's doc_root is empty (i.e. `doc_root =`)

I can't use `rename()` to move something out of the doc root and I can't use fwrite() to create a file outside of it either.

Just to verify, I exec'd `whoami` from a php file and it echo'd/returned apache when accessed in the browser.

I think I've hit google with about 200 searchs about this so far and I guess I'm still missing something.

Comment: Have you checked your `open_basedir` settings using `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Do directories leading up to `somedir` need to be readable by the apache user as well?

Comment: open_basedir is commented out, so it's seems from what I read that it would not be a factor in that case???

Comment: Only somedir needs to be read/write by Apache.

Comment: `open_basedir` cannot be _commented out_ in `phpinfo()` output... Do yourself and us a favor, check it......

Comment: It's commented out in php.ini, and listed as "open_basedir no value no value" in phpinfo()

Comment: There is also no php_admin_value override for open_basdir in httpd.conf

Comment: what errors do you get ? check php logs if your errors are suppressed in the script.

Comment: The php exception thrown is "rename(/var/www/html/objects,/var/somedir/objects): Permission denied" AND for some reason php is not logging it's errors to /var/log/php.errors even though I have it configured in php.ini and log_errors is on.

Comment: Just my two cents: did it come to your mind that there is a reason why the *Security Enhanced Linux* profile prevented php from writing outside document root? And what do you think happened when you deactivated an security enhancement? I can not think of a single case that should make it necessary or even feasible to deactivate a security measure for an exposed machine which could not be solved by proper application design.

Comment: SOLUTION is given at this link and also below :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882244/php-fopen-permission-denied

chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/directory_to_write
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/html/directory_to_write
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/directory_to_write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that selinux was in fact enabled although my "linux guy" assured me that it was not!

Comment: Something like this happened just the other day for someone else ;-)  Search doesn't hurt... :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998743/rhel-php-writing-files-outside-var-www-html/8998776