# Why does PHP need "execute" privilege to write a file?

Tags: php, linux

I can't fopen a file for writing unless I enable "execute" permission for the directory that it's being created in. That seems strange. Why is "write" permission not enough?

It's a very simple fopen, fputcsv loop, fclose sequence. Nothing else is being done with files in that directory.

Basic config - Centos, Apache, PHP

Thanks

Comment: This might have to do with SELinux (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) since you are using CentOS.

Answer (score 2):

"On a directory, the execute permission (also called the "search bit") allows you to access files in the directory and enter it, with the cd command, for example." [source](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/filepermissions.html) -- good discussion of file permissions

Answer (score 1):

This might have to do with [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux).  Basically, SELinux gives you more control over what processes and daemons can do... a sort of boundary system that goes beyond the normal user/group permissions.  It can be helpful for fine-grained control, but it can get in the way, sometimes.

There are ways to turn it off (see http://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-selinux).

But, there are also ways to fine-tune the settings (see: http://sheltren.com/stop-disabling-selinux) which might be better in the long run.  You could also try a different distro if you aren't tied to CentOS.

**EDIT:**

Also, if this doesn't have to do with SELinux, as [sepp2k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149392/sepp2k) mentioned in the comments below, you may want to take a look at the section titled "**Execute Permission**" on [this file and directory reference guide](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/AUnix1/FilePermissions.htm) by Wayne Pollock.

Comment: This has nothing to do with SELinux. You can't create, modify or read files in a directory that you don't have execute permissions on. That's normal behavior.

Comment: Something like this type of question has been asked recently here on SO... (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998743/rhel-php-writing-files-outside-var-www-html/8998776) and (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056628/php-cant-write-outside-of-the-document-root-no-matter-what/9059696) Maybe I'm wrong.  Doesn't hurt to post your own answer, as well.

Comment: You do bring up a good point about `execute` permissions, though: http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/AUnix1/FilePermissions.htm  (Execute Permission section)  Edited my answer to reflect that possibility.