# ../filepath/ is not working on my webserver?

Tags: php

I am trying to direct a scripts include out of it's sub-directory back to the root directory and into includes/config.php

I'v done this, but it doesn't seem to be working on my webhost, it works fine on localhost though;

```
include_once "../includes/config.php";
```

The directory the file that contains the include in is only one sub-directory deep so I figured ../ would work, which it did on localhost but for some reason it doesn't work when I upload it to my localhost.

Could anyone explain why this isn't working?

Comment: I had a similar problem, which wound up being related to security configs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998743/rhel-php-writing-files-outside-var-www-html

Comment: The permissions on the directory may need to be changed

Comment: Switched it over to absolute paths, thank you fabio, little extra work but it gets the job done.

Comment: Please don't use absolute paths. Or you will hate both yourself and @Fabio once you have to migrate the site. Use either `dirname(__FILE__) . '/relative/path/to/file.php'` or `__DIR__ . '/relative/path/to/file.php'`. http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php