# PHP - fopen(file.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied when trying to handle file.txt file

Tags: php, fopen, handle

Code:

```
if (isset($_POST['ta'])) {
    $newData = nl2br (htmlspecialchars($_POST['ta'])); 
    $handle = fopen($myFile, "w");
    fwrite($handle, $newdata);
    fclose($handle);
}
```

gives me the error of:

> Warning: fopen(file.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/eduardoCMS/file.php on line 12

does anyone know why this is and how I could fix that. thank you guys for all the help, much apprecaited

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882244/php-fopen-permission-denied maybe this could help you. (Possible duplicate?)

Comment: I guess, you need to give the relative path to your file and if you are on Linux, try to change the file permission using `sudo chmod 777 file.txt`

Comment: you you were right i didnt give the permission to 777 thank you very much